# Does javascript handle objects by reference or by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
var myObjects = {}; //global variable

//Later on in the code:
for (i in myObjects)
{
    var obj = myObjects[i];
    process(obj);
}

function process(obj)
{
    $.getJSON("example.com/process/", {id: obj.id}, function(result)
      {
          //Will the following change the permanent/global copy e.g 
          // myObjects[44] ?
          obj.addItem(result.id, result.name, result.number);
      }
    );
}
```

Will the following line:

```
     obj.addItem(result.id, result.name, result.number);
```

modify the object by value or by reference, i.e will it modify the local copy of `obj` or e.g `myObjects[44]`?

If it affects only the local copy, how can I have it change the global copy of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive variables are passed by value in JavaScript, but objects are passed by reference.

Source and further reading:

- [JavaScript: Passing by Value or by Reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Comment: Note that it's a little weirder than that: if you create a string by calling "new String('hi mom')" then it works kind-of like a string sometimes, but it'll act like an Object for parameter passing. That is, it's passed by reference.

Comment: Actually, strings are immutable in js. Therefore, you are always passing them by reference. All operations on strings return a new string.

Comment: In JavaScript, when you pass an object, you are really passing an object reference by value.  See this [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/518069/379428).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is pass by value, as has been clarified in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/518069/379428). (Someone with more powers should mark this as duplicate--the answers here are incorrect.)

Answer (score 0):

all non-object variables are pass-by-value afaik..