# Javascript call by reference not working

Tags: javascript

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) and tried implementing my function so that data doesn't change back, but it isn't working with me.

I have an array of objects, where I send them one by one to another function, to add data.

```
queries.first(finalObject.sectionProjects[i]);
```

for each one of the `sectionProjects`, there is a variable `achievements`, with an empty array.

Upon sending each sectionProject to `the queries.first` function, I reassign achievements,

```
finalObject.sectionProjects[i].achievements = something else
```

When I return from the queries.first function, I lose the data I added.
Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the function:

```
module.exports = {
    first:function(aProject) {

        // Latest achievements
        var query =
                " SELECT ta.description, ta.remarks, ta.expectedECD " +
                " FROM project pr, task ta, milestone mi " +
                " WHERE pr.ID = mi.project_ID AND mi.ID = ta.milestone_ID " +
                " AND ta.achived = ta.percent AND pr.ID = " + aProject.project_id +
                " ORDER BY pr.expectedECD " +
                " LIMIT 5;"
        ;

        var stringified = null;
        pmdb.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            connection.query(query,  function(err, rows){
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }else{
                    var jsonRows = [];
                    for( var i in rows) {       
                        stringified = JSON.stringify(rows[i]); 
                        jsonRows.push(JSON.parse(stringified));
                    }       
                    connection.release();                       

                    aProject.achievements = jsonRows;
                    upcomingTasks(aProject);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is pmdb.js:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "database"
});

module.exports = con;
```

This is the main function that calls queries.first:

```
// ...Code...
//Number of section projects
var len = jsonRows.length;
console.log("Number of section projects: " + len);
var internal_counter = 0;   

function callbackFun(i){

    (finalObject.sectionProjects[i]).achievements = [];

    queries.first(finalObject.sectionProjects[i]);

    if(++internal_counter === len) {
        response.json(finalObject);
    }
}

var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    funcs[i] = callbackFun.bind(this, i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: You need to share `queries.first`, how is it implemented, is it an async one etc

Comment: post your function which is assigning the achievements. So I can debug. Also make fiddle

Comment: your function seems ok. post fiddle to debug your code. or post complete code for better understanding.

Comment: is this `pmdb.getConnection` async function ?

Answer (score 1):

Read [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) Answer twice. Objects acts as a wrapper for the scalar primitive property. You are passing the Objects in to the "queries.first" function.

See this [Object reference issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341159/object-reference-issue)

Edited for the sample code

```
    pmdb.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query(query,  function(err, rows){
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }else{
                var jsonRows = [];
                for( var i in rows) {       
                    stringified = JSON.stringify(rows[i]); 
                    jsonRows.push(JSON.parse(stringified));
                }       
                connection.release();                       

                aProject.achievements = jsonRows;
                upcomingTasks(aProject)
            }
        });
    });
```

that is not a problem. change it like this. "upcomingTasks" is not a callback function. it is execute after assign the achievements in aProject

Comment: I'm changing my variable using the dot '.' operator, which follows the 'Object reference issue' link, and I'm applying it obj1 in the first link, so can you tell me what it is I should look at?

Comment: I changed it, but it's still not changing. I'll add code from the main function